# Bootstrap-datepicker not rendering correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Ive searched and searched and cant find out why my datepicker isn't rendering properly. The visual format is off, things aren't aligned correctly and today's date isn't highlighted, as well as the mouse icon not changing to the "hand" selector icon.

Any ideas? Here is my code and JSFiddle link:

HTML

```
<div class="input-append date input-group" id="dpStartDate" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly> 
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#dpStartDate').datepicker({
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tyv2atL7/

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work, you have to add the CSS for the Datepicker in JSFiddle.

Just click on external ressources and insert

```
http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css
```

Working Link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyv2atL7/2/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @wesleybland this was a jsfiddle setup problem, not invalid code. I  editet it, so its clearer now